# How to export PGP key (in clear text?)?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, google-chrome-extensions, pgp

I created a set of PGP keys in Kleopatra using GPG4Win. I want to use my private and public keys to encrypt and decrypt emails with this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailvelope/kajibbejlbohfaggdiogboambcijhkke I imported the public key fine, but it seems that the extension also needs the private key. I am wondering how to export the private key (in plain text I guess) so that I can use it in the extension. I can't believe I have been unable to find a solution for this on my own, so any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The following should do the trick:

```
$ gpg --armor --export-secret-keys 0x<keyid>
```